# Can't connect to MySQL through MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

So here's my array containing my credentials.

```
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '*',
    'db' => 's'
)
```

And the actual connection

```
 try{
    $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/username'));
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

And this is the error I get

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

But I am aware that this means  access is denied, but the credentials are 100% correct. I also tested via command line and through workbench.

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure a password is set? What happens if you attempt to connect via the command line line this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot
```

Also, the password for `root` in MAMP is `root`. This is no deep/dark secret. Is the `*` in your example valid?

And in your connector, have you tried using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`? I have seen some MySQL setups work with one but not the other when it should be both.

**EDIT:** If you somehow mucked up the `root` password, don’t panic! You can still reset it this way. Warning, some folks feel this method of password reset is “risky” but that is generally true for a production server or any server in the wild. From MAMP on your desktop, this should be 100% safe.

First, stop MAMP entirely.

Next, start it up again from the command line with the `skip-grant-tables` option like so:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

Once that is done, you can login with 100% no password just like this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot
```

Then you can reset the `root` password with this one-liner:

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE user='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

Okay, now find the process running the MySQL daemon with `skip-grant-tables` from the command line like this:

```
ps -u [your system username] | grep "mysqld --skip-grant-tables"
```

A list with two items should be returned: One is the `mysqld` & the other is the command you just made. Something like this:

```
502  1759 ttys004    0:00.11 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables
502  1766 ttys004    0:00.00 grep mysqld
```

Okay, so now we know the `mysqld` with `skip-grant-tables` has process ID 1759, go ahead and kill that like so:

```
kill 1759
```

Restart MAMP again & the `root` password should work as expected now.

Comment: I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. And the `*` is just a placeholder. Also tried `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I still get `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)` When doing `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot`

Comment: Also can't I just use the built in feature? I'm using MAMP Pro

Comment: this helped solve a problem of two days... only thing on the internet that worked... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a port to your array! For me, it worked! The port is 8889 by default. You can change it by going to MAMP>Preferences, then the Ports tab. Here's what I think (I haven't tried this!):

```
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '*',
    'port' => '8889',
    'db' => 's'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `Config::get('mysql/username')` twice, the second should be `Config::get('mysql/password')`

Comment: let the connection string echo out first, to see if it is correct! `$s='mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db').','.Config::get('mysql/username').','.Config::get('mysql/password'); echo $s;`

Comment: I get `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=s,root,Array`

Comment: This means, that your mysql password is not set up correctly in the configuration. Maybe you simply mistyped something?

Comment: I guess I got it working now since I have `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=s,root,*`, but now I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /Users/idrisk/Desktop/localhost/classes/DB.php on line 12`

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot the `=`, but now yet another problem. I get `SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 's,root,*'`

Comment: You misedited! You need `.','.` for the echo, but just `,` for the new()

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8fca914ad1670bb1edb3 This is what I have. Isn't it fine?

Comment: No, it isn't: You want `$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));`

Comment: But then I get his `SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Again: To **echo** the line, you need `.','.`, to use it for PDO you just need the commas.

Comment: I am echoing with `.','.`, but now I get `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=s,root,Array`, and there isn't any `Array` anywhere...

Comment: The password is not set up correctly: `Config::get('mysql/password')` returns an array, not the password

Comment: Before we proceed: Just try `$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), "wayne123");`, so that we see, if it is the `Config::get()` or not.

Comment: I get `SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`...

Comment: OK: So the password is just wrong. Fix it and retry.

Comment: And you changed it on the DB **and** in the PHP code?